# why is spring boot returning me a json with null for some values?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I'm making a game for practice.

I have a spring boot/Maven project connected to a MySQL database. I was able to setup an api that simply retrieves everything from my "allriddles" table. It worked before, but now the api returns a json where some values are null for some keys. The only thing i was playing with was the application.properties on the spring boot file. I was hopping between "update" and "none" for the spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto.
What could I have done wrong?

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/riddlesgame
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=RiddlesGame886
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api/v1
server.port=8088
```

this is the database table and expected columns

[image: database table and columns]

this is the returned json with erronous null values

[image: returned json with erroneous null values]

here is the model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "allriddles")
public class Riddle {

/*
 * ATTRIBUTES
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String title;
private int difficulty;
private String prize;
private String riddlerName;
private int levels;
private String riddleDescription;

/*
 * CONSTRUCTORS
 */
public Riddle() {}
public Riddle( String title, int difficulty, String prize, String riddlerName, int levels,
        String description) {
    super();
    
    this.title = title;
    this.difficulty = difficulty;
    this.prize = prize;
    this.riddlerName = riddlerName;
    this.levels = levels;
    this.riddleDescription = description;
}
}
```

this is my controller that calls a service

```
 @RestController
 public class GetRiddles {

@Autowired
RiddlesService rs; 


@RequestMapping("/Riddles")
public List<Riddle> getAllRiddles(){
    return rs.getAllRiddles();
}
```

the service that calls crud

```
@Service
public class RiddlesService {

@Autowired
RiddlesRepository riddlesRepository;

public List<Riddle> getAllRiddles(){
    List<Riddle> riddles = new ArrayList<>();
    riddlesRepository.findAll()
    .forEach(riddles::add);
    

    return riddles;
}
```

the crud interface

```
public interface RiddlesRepository extends CrudRepository<Riddle, Integer> {

}
```

and finally the console output if thats of any help

[image: trace]

Comment: can you add generated sql from stacktrace

Comment: Please share the api code, from where you are returning this JSON

Comment: @Kandy I added the console output

Comment: @Sunil I used a RestController, Service, and CRUD jpa . I added them to the code. My apologies

Comment: add controller part also

Comment: @Kandy The controller was on there. You must have missed it due to formatting on my part. Do you mind taking another look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same thing, and got a similar result. It occurred, as you said, upon modifying spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto to update. It ended up adding 2 new columns.

```
Hibernate: alter table allriddles add column riddle_description varchar(255)
Hibernate: alter table allriddles add column riddler_name varchar(255)
```

The original column names were riddleDescription and riddlerName and those remained with existing values. But the new columns will not have data in them. So assuming I recreated the same issue you had, either you have to

- in the database: move data from old columns (without the underscore) to new columns (with the underscore) and remove old columns. Or
- in the database: remove new columns (with the underscore). in Riddle.java change properties `riddlerName` and `riddleDescription` to `riddlername` and `riddledescription`.

I assume possibly you might have also changed at some point between all lower case and camelcase for those property names. Because camelcase properties will map to database as underscores (e.g. code - riddleName -> db column - riddle_name), while all lowercase will not have underscores (e.g. code - riddlername -> db column - riddlerName or riddlername).

Comment: This was exactly it. I appreciate you. Could I ask how exactly did you know this was the problem? I wouldn't know where to even look for this type of documentation if it weren't for stackoverflow

Comment: @GioPoe I ran with your code snippets and tried it out, and then in logs noticed that it was adding 2 columns, noticing that it adds underscores for camelcase.  Then googled for mapping JPA properties and saw this useful article https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-field-naming-spring-boot (you can make your own strategies). I do like Sunil's answer about being explicit with column names, I tend to like being a bit more explicit sometimes rather having implicit mappings as this.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default way in which hibernate names columns in the table based on the fields defined in the entity.

To override the default behaviour you can use

```
@Column(name = "riddleName")
private String riddlerName;

@Column(name = "riddleDescription")
private String riddleDescription;
```